# How to save convolutional layers result images as png or jpg or any other formats?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I can't find the right way to save output images of intermediate layers. suppose I have trained a convolutional network and after the training I want to put the fully connected layers away and SAVE  output images of last convolutional layer in order to put some of them in my research paper, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends what you mean by 'convolution layers result images'.

These layers are not images as such, they are just a collection of weights for each filter in a layer. We can seek to visualise these by passing in random noise then gradually updating to maximise a given filters activation. I suspect this is what you mean?

This process is explained quite nicely in the following article but is probably a little broad to address in detail here. Perhaps you could attempt to recreate this and follow-up with more specific questions if you get stuck.

https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-visualize-convolutional-features-in-40-lines-of-code-70b7d87b0030

Comment: Thank You Very much Stewart_R for guiding me and providing me with this useful article link

Comment: @SHAHEENALHIRMIZY My pleasure, glad you found it useful. If it helped you then you can always accept and/or upvote